# DataTable not accepted by svcutil - WCF Service

Tags: wcf, datatable, svcutil.exe

I'm having very strange issue with my WCF Service Proxy client generated by "svcutil.exe" . My WCF Service works very fine if I don't have a function that returns DataTable. As soon as I add a method that returns a DataTable the client generated by svcutil.exe is behaving very strangely. The Interface is no longer found and client is not able to call the service. But if I add as a Service Reference its working very smoothly. I know its not a good habit to use DataTable as a return type but I need to. I cannot use the Service Reference :-( Any idea why its behaving or what I'm missing!!!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the **DataTableSurrogate** class. It is used by the SyncFramework for serialization and really easy to use.
[MSDN DataTableSurrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.synchronization.data.datatablesurrogate.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply ll try that but I'm curious to know is there any way for making svcutil to work with DataTable????

Comment: @Michael : Sorry but this is not the answer I;m looking for :-(

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really serialize datasets, instead you should use datamodels and keep anything to do with datasets, tables, readers etc on your backend & in the business layer.

But.. if you want to do so you need to add the following "include" in svcutil, which is causing your issue. (Tells to reuse the types defined in System.Data.dll and not generate them in the proxy)

```
/r:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll
```