# Why is it a bad practice to return DataTables from WCF service operations?

Tags: wcf

I know that the preferred way to serialize complex types in WCF is by using DataContracts but why is it so?

If I return a DataTable instead of a DataContract from my service operations does WCF use the XmlSerializer class instead of the default DataContractSerializer?

And lastly, in this topic: [DataTable not accepted by svcutil - WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742997/datatable-not-accepted-by-svcutil-wcf-service)

Do you think that the problem is that by returning a DataTable the CLR types don't map correctly to XSD schema definitions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem with using DataTable in your service contract is not a technical problem but a design problem.  If your service is using DataTable in the contract, then you are violating SOA design principles of using standardized contracts and loose coupling.
This is because if a service returns a DataTable, the contract doesn't specify what columns that DataTable contains.  That will force the service consumer to have some knowledge of the inner workings of the service provider, making the system tightly coupled.

Comment: So it is all about interoperability. Considering my service clients are all .NET 4, I lost a couple of hours writing a DataContract instead of returning a DataTable with 50+ columns :)

Comment: @Pantelis it is not all about interoperability. As GTG already pointed out, the data contract is not well defined: should columns change, the client could break because of those changes, while the data contract would remain the same. Strongly typed datasets address this issue and may theoretically be a viable solution for intranet applications, though I didn't really have a need to use them in this context yet so I can't say how well it works in practice (see also [this old post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,d88f7539-10d8-4697-8c6e-1badb08bb3f5.aspx))

Comment: Yeah, I've read this post yesterday. Makes sense. Well, a DataContract not written well, could also break existing clients if you don't implement IExtensibleDataObject. But yes, I get the point! Thanks.